# How to create a Git Repository with synchronised and tracking submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

In simple terms I would like to create a Parent/Child repository where the Child is a submodule and its branch should track that of its parent.

I have been trying to get this working and thought I understood what I was doing but clearly I am missing something.

All seems to be setup correctly in config files until I switch branches 'Main -> UAT-> Main' and I end up with Child still in uat and if changes are committed to the Child, it looses its HEAD.

To keep things as simple as possible I would like to get this to working locally first.

git version 2.38.1.windows.1

Here are my steps

```
# Setup main
# ------------
md Parent
cd Parent
git init
echo "Hello" > ReadMe.txt
git add .
git commit -m "Initialising Parent main"    
cd ..

md Child
cd Child
git init
echo "Hello" > ReadMe.txt
git add .
git commit -m "Initialising Child main"
cd ..

# Add Submodule
# ------------------
cd Parent
git config --global protocol.file.allow always
git config submodule.recurse true
git config submodule.update rebase
git config push.recurseSubmodules on-demand
git submodule add -b main ..\Child
git add .
git commit -m "Added submodule"
git log --oneline
# All good on main branch
cd Child
git log --oneline
# All good on main branch
cd ..\..

# Setup uat
# -----------
cd Parent
git switch -c uat --recurse-submodules
cd Child
#! -- recurse-submodules didn't work 
# Child still on main so switch manually
git switch -c uat
echo "Hello again" > Readme.txt
git add .
git commit -m "Initialising Child uat"
cd ..
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.Child.branch uat
git add .
git commit -m "Initialising Main at"
git log --oneline
# All good on uat branch
cd Child
git log --oneline
# All good on uat branch
cd ..\..

# Switch all to main
# ---------------------
# SPOILER Child Looses its HEAD
cd Parent
git switch main --recurse-submodules
cd Child
git log --oneline
#! Child lost its HEAD
```

## Update

Thanks @torek for suggestion to use

```
git submodule foreach git switch <branch>
```

But I though the whole point of `--recursive-submodules` together with config settings

```
git config submodule.recurse true
git config submodule.update rebase
git config push.recurseSubmodules on-demand
```

was to automate this

In fact I was of the understanding that `git config submodule.recurse true` should mean `--recurse-submodules` was implied for all operations that support it, except clone, and that `git config push.recurseSubmodules on-demand` would ensure warning on attempts to commit a parent having changes in submodules.

Comment: Branch names in submodules are largely irrelevant. You simply can't do this. You can do something different: run `git switch <name> && git submodule foreach git switch <name>`.